# Matrix image with shattered glass effect

Tags: graphics, matrices, tikz-matrix

I have a matrix whose primary dimension is infinite and want a way to reflect this in the matrix diagram itself. The following image is not what I want, but it illustrates the jist. I would prefer to have a matrix whose lowest row looks like the rows that would otherwise be there have shattered off (think of cartoon broken glass edge effect).

[image]

Just to emphasise that I do not want to replicate this image exactly - I'm only after a shattered edge effect (that is more jagged than this example). Is there an easy way to achieve this?

Comment: maybe https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86372/torn-paper-matching-up-the-torn-edges could help

Comment: Or https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438534/121799 All you need to do is to add an appropriate decoration. In your case this seems to be rather straightforward. Some slight modification of [Jake's complete sines](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25689/121799) may already do the job.

Answer (score 2):

One out of many possibilities. Notice that with `complete sines` the distances are quantized, meaning that if you change some distance a bit the impact can be larger than expected.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix}
% from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/25689/121799
\usetikzlibrary{decorations}
\pgfdeclaredecoration{complete sines}{initial}
{
    \state{initial}[
        width=+0pt,
        next state=sine,
        persistent precomputation={\pgfmathsetmacro\matchinglength{
            \pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength / int(\pgfdecoratedinputsegmentlength/\pgfdecorationsegmentlength)}
            \setlength{\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{\matchinglength pt}
        }] {}
    \state{sine}[width=\pgfdecorationsegmentlength]{
        \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathsine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{-0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
        \pgfpathcosine{\pgfpoint{0.25\pgfdecorationsegmentlength}{0.5\pgfdecorationsegmentamplitude}}
}
    \state{final}{}
}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[decoration={complete sines,amplitude=8pt, segment length=11pt}]
\matrix (m) [fill=blue!20,matrix of nodes,inner sep=0pt,
nodes={draw,minimum width=9mm,minimum height=5mm},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,row sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,]%
{
105 & 102 & 96 & \phantom{123}\\
103 & 99 & 107 & \phantom{123}\\
101 & 98 & 105 & \phantom{123}\\
\phantom{123} & \phantom{123} & \phantom{123} & \phantom{123} \\
};
\fill[white,decorate,overlay] ([xshift=6mm,yshift=10pt]m.north east) coordinate (tl)
 -- ([xshift=-5mm,yshift=10pt]m.north east)
 --  ([xshift=-5mm,yshift=10pt]m.south east) 
 -- ([xshift=-5pt,yshift=10pt]m.south west) 
 -- ++ (0,-18pt) -| cycle;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Another possibility is to clip the matrix against some (predefined) shape. I am using a cloud here, but it could be anything.

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{matrix,shapes}
\makeatletter
\tikzset{ % https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/38995/121799
  use path/.code={\pgfsyssoftpath@setcurrentpath{#1}}
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\node[cloud,save path=\Cloud,aspect=2,cloud puffs=20,
minimum width=4.5cm,minimum height=2.5cm%,draw
] (cloud){};
\clip[use path=\Cloud];
\end{pgfinterruptboundingbox}
\matrix (m) at ([xshift=3mm,yshift=-3mm]cloud.north west) [anchor=north west,
fill=blue!20,matrix of nodes,inner sep=0pt,
nodes={draw,minimum width=9mm,minimum height=5mm},
column sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,row sep=-\pgflinewidth/2,]%
{
105 & 102 & 96 & \phantom{123}\\
103 & 99 & 107 & \phantom{123}\\
101 & 98 & 105 & \phantom{123}\\
\phantom{123} & \phantom{123} & \phantom{123} & \phantom{123} \\
};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(One does not seem to be able to put a matrix in a `path picture` easily, otherwise that would simplify things here.)