# How to draw a kraft paper bag with a zigzag side?

Tags: tikz-styles

I need to draw a rectangle with a zigzag side as a kraft paper bag. How can I fill it properly with the color?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{xcolor}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\tikzset{zigzag/.style={decorate,decoration=zigzag}}
\definecolor{sandybrown}{rgb}{0.96, 0.64, 0.38}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[thick,sandybrown,zigzag] (-2,0) coordinate(a) -- (2,0) coordinate(b);
\coordinate (r) at (-2,-5);
\coordinate (n) at (2,-5);
\draw[fill=sandybrown] (a) -- (r) -- (n) -- (b);
\draw[thick,sandybrown,zigzag] (-2,0) coordinate(a) -- (2,0) coordinate(b);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I learned this trick from Mark Wibrow, see e.g. [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/438534/121799). You can decorate just some stretch of a full path that gets filled (or clipped against or whatever).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3.14mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}
\definecolor{sandybrown}{rgb}{0.96, 0.64, 0.38}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[decoration={zigzag,segment length={4cm/10.5}},fill=sandybrown] (2,0) |- ++ (-4,-5)
-- ++ (0,5) decorate { -- cycle};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]