# Tikz: Drawing "random" paths in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, graphs, best-practices

I am working on Graph Theory and I have to draw paths that seem quite random such as the ones on the 1st image. I have created the paths *P,Q* on the 2nd image using the code below.

[image]
[image]

However, it seems really frustrating having to add more points to achieve more definition and having to change "ins" and "outs" of paths to "generate randomness".

*What I'm really asking for* is a more practical way to generate paths such as *P,Q*, that could then, of course, be impelemnted to produce something like the graph on the 1st image.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}[line cap=round]

%  Path P
\draw[thick]
    (-5,2) to[out=20, in=170] ++(0.5,0.1)
           to[out=-2, in=130] ++(0.5,+0)
           to[out=-40, in=168] ++(0.5,-0.07)          
           to[out=-10, in=170] ++(0.5,+0.05)       
           to[out=-10, in=120] ++(0.5,0) 
           to[out=300, in=170] ++(0.5,+0.05)       
           to[out=-20, in=120] ++(0.5,+0.05) coordinate (u)    
           to[out=-20, in=170] ++(0.5,0) 
           to[out=-10, in=170] ++(0.5,+0.05) coordinate (P)  
    ;
    
    \node[shift={(0.2,0)}] at (P) {$\mathrm{P}$};
% Path Q
\draw[thick]
    (-5,0) to[out=300, in=160] ++(0.5,-0.1)
           to[out=-10, in=170] ++(0.5,0)  
           to[out=-2, in=175] ++(0.5,+0.1) coordinate (y)
           to[out=-4, in=178] ++(0.5,-0.1) 
           to[out=-2, in=210] ++(0.5,+0) 
           to[out=30, in=190] ++(0.5,0.05) coordinate (v)
           to[out=+10, in=130] ++(0.5,+0.05)       
           to[out=-30, in=160] ++(0.5,0) 
           to[out=-20, in=220] ++(0.5,+0.05) coordinate (Q)
    ;
    \node[shift={(0.2,0)}] at (Q) {$\mathrm{Q}$};

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Did you look at the answers to this one?  https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/273795/15036

Answer (score 2):

Here's a way to do it.

- `\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}`
- defining `decoration`, with some overwrite for Q (`rounded corners`)
- use `relative polar coordinates` to set end points
- storing `coordinates` of end points
- placing `nodes` with labels there

However, tikz sometimes needs a lot of resources when varying parameters for segment length and rounded corners.

[image: result]

```
\documentclass[10pt,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{decorations.pathmorphing}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
% see 50.3.1 Decorations Producing Straight Line Paths
    [decoration={random steps,segment length=3mm}]
    % paths
    \draw [decorate]                (0,0) -- (10:5)     coordinate (P);
    \draw [decorate,
            rounded corners=1mm]    (0,-1) -- ++(-5:5)  coordinate (Q);
    % labels
    \node at (P) [xshift=5mm] {P};
    \node at (Q) [xshift=5mm] {Q};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```